# Calculating running total and simultaneously dividing by multiples of 2 [using excel]

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please refer to the attached image.

We have some numbers in column B. Need help to generate numbers similar to those shown in column E, which is running total of B divided by 2, 4, 6 and so on for each comming row.

To show an example we have generated the ans in column E taking help of two intermediary columns C and D.

[image]

Is there any way which can help do this in one column only.

--
Thanks,
Kunal

Explained in problem statement.

Comment: Please include sample data with expected results.

Comment: So if the first one that is divided by 2 is in row 2 then use =A2/row(). Add an if() to test if even so odd numbers don't calculate. Drag down. No image provided, no data showing what you are working with so can't do much more.

Comment: sorry Mike, it somehow got missed. Just revised the post with the relevant image. Thank you for your efforts :)

Answer (score 0):

So, just to show the first part using the row numbers:

[image]

Then for cumulative, in row 3 start adding the previous result from B2 like so: (do note the subtle update to the formula)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `SCAN` function to do running totals combined with `SEQUENCE` to do the division. In cell `B2` put the following:

```
=SCAN(0, A2:A6, LAMBDA(ac,x, ac+x))/SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A6),,2,2)
```

or using `LET` to avoid repetition:

```
=LET(A, A2:A6, SCAN(0, A, LAMBDA(ac,x, ac+x))/SEQUENCE(ROWS(A),,2,2))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

You can achieve the same (more verbose) via `MMULT` and building a Lower Unit Triangle Matrix `N((SEQUENCE(n)>=TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(n))))` then:

```
=LET(A,A2:A6,n,ROWS(A),s,SEQUENCE(n),MMULT(N((s>=TRANSPOSE(s))),A)
 /SEQUENCE(n,,2,2))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, David. All three solutions worked perfectly. Will explore these more to understand further.